# Setup nginx with react and express

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I have a nginx server currently up and running, however I can only acces my website and not mywebsite/contact for exemple.

I have a react build as frontend @ : /usr/share/nginx/site/front
And a express server running with pm2 @ port 5000. in /usr/share/nginx/site/express

I would like all requests to /api go to the express server running on port 5000.
The rest should go to my react front end, Normally the react build will automatically proxy all /api/ requests to the port 5000 express server, this works locally.

How would I have to change the default nginx config @ sites-available/

I currently have :

```
server{
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server
  root /usr/share/nginx/site/front

  index index.html
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    server {
    listen      80  default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;


    location /api/ {    # Backend
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:500;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/back.out.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/back.err.log;
    }



    location / {    # Frontend
        root        /usr/share/nginx/site/front;
        index       index.html;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/front.out.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/front.err.log;
    }
}
```